# How do I start a tmux session on a remote machine and also run a command in said tmux session

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, tmux

I have the following code which I have been using for years but has broken recently when I upgraded my systems (from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04)

```
_SNAME=$1-$2

TERM=xterm ssh x.y.z.com -t tmux new-session -A -s $_SNAME \'ssh $1\'
```

What this did for me was:

1. If the tmux session exists, connect to it
2. If the tmux session didn't exist, create a new tmux session and SSH to my remote server

However, after upgrading my OS, it is broken and now I just get `[exited]`.

The problem seems to be when I specify a command to run within the tmux session (the `\'ssh $1\'` part)

Has tmux changed the syntax for this?  I have found another way to do this with `tmux send-keys` but it is far less clean

Answer (score 0):

Your quoting is (possibly) messed up.  Possibly, because your command does seem to work for me.  Instead of sending literal single quotes, just make sure that the command is quoted:

```sh
_SNAME="$1-$2"
TERM=xterm ssh -t x.y.z.com tmux new-session -A -s "$_SNAME" "ssh $1"
```

What is probably happening for you is that the command `'ssh` can't be found.

You could also try using `"'ssh $1'"` as the last argument, but that would be equivalent to what you are already trying.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Unfortunately this still didn't fix the problem.  It did get rid of the [exited] message (not necessarily sure this is good or bad) but it just immediately brings me back to my local terminal and there is no tmux session created on x.y.z.com

Strangely enough, this code alone will at least correctly create the tmux session on my remote machine:
`TERM=xterm ssh -t x.y.z.com tmux new-session -A -s "$_SNAME"`
but whenever i try to add the command to the end, it doesn't work.